# Converting a matrix into a gray scale image in R

Tags: r, image, image-processing

I have the following vector:

```
 vec<-as.vector(rnorm(1:924))
```

And would like to reshape it into a matrix of the form 33 X 28. Then convert the matrix into a gray scale pixel like image.

In MATLAB, I know there exists *imagesc* and *imshow* to convert the matrix into an image. Is there something similar in R ?

Also, can the mean and maximum be adjusted like in MATLAB for the gray scale intensity?

Comment: BTW: you don't need the `as.vector()`. `rnorm()` already returns a vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `?heatmap`:

```
heatmap(matrix(vec,33,28),Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col=paste("gray",1:99,sep=""))
```

[image: heatmap]

You can adjust the min/max color via the `col` argument. Look at `?image`, `?heat.colors` and friends.

Comment: You do need to take care to add `scale="none"` if you don't want the values to be scaled within each row.

Answer (score 1):

Not drastically different from Stephan's answer, but if you want to give a fuller range of grays, here is what you can do:

```
grays = rgb(red = 0:255/255, blue = 0:255/255, green = 0:255/255)
heatmap(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10),Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col=grays, scale = "none")
```